# Save data from cpp into bytes that can be pickle loaded by Python and seen as numpy ndarray

Tags: c++, boost, pickle, numpy-ndarray

**PROBLEM**

Let's say I have a python script that works with a numpy ndarray and then `pickle.dumps` it into bytes. Another python script would then `pickle.loads` those bytes and see the object as a numpy ndarray. Easy.

I have to replicate the first part in cpp, meaning:

- I mostly work with gsl_vector and gsl_matrix, so first I need to convert into a cpp ndarray implementation.
- Then pickle that cpp ndarray into bytes that can be pickle loaded by python and seen as numpy ndarray.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

By looking around in stackoverflow, I have found

- boost libraries have an implementation of numpy ndarray [ndarray.hpp] and may also support the pickle part.
  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html
  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/topics/pickle_support.html#topics.pickle_support.introduction
- picklingtools seem to cover the pickle part, and there is an example on how to convert a user-defined class into a Val, so it can be dumped [DumpValToArray].
  https://www.picklingtools.com/html/usersguide.html#appendix-a-c-and-user-defined-types

**QUESTION**
So, the hard part seems to convert a boost ndarray object into a picklingtools Val object that can be dumped.
I could not find any example for that and any help on this would be great.

Moreover, being ndarray and pickle such common classes, I wonder if there is a faster-easier way to pickle them in cpp, rather than passing through two different libraries and manually building the conversion from the ndarray class to Val.

Comment: Have you considered using the [C NumPy API](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/array.html#array-structure-and-data-access)? You could use `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` to wrap a NumPy array around a chunk of memory with a given shape, and then immediately call `PyArray_Dump` to dump it into an open filehandle. The only downside is that the pickling process will create another copy in memory, if I read the code correctly. Oh well, that's what you get with generic interfaces.